# How can compare and exclude arrays elements with other arrays elements in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to compare two arrays
here is one arrays
[...showid]
here is another arrays
[...swipeeachotheruserId]

in this arrays ,some id will contains
this ids will same but not all are same
[ 3, 5 , 7 , 10 ,14 ] [ 2, 5, 7, 1, 20, 14 ]

some elements will be same but not all elements same

logic is

showid===swipeeachotheruserId ? will exclude not same id and display here : show id

how can compare and exclude this arrays values

Comment: What's the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to pass the objects which are in both arrays, use this:

```
return showid.filter(e=>sipeeachotheruserid.includes(e))
```

if you want to pass the objects which are noth in swipeachotheruserid, then use this:

```
return showid.filter(e=>!swipeeachotheruserid.includes(e))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const showid = [ 3, 5, 7 , 10 ,14 ];
const swipeeachotheruserId = [ 2, 5, 7, 1, 20, 14 ];

const duplicates = showid.filter(value => swipeeachotheruserId.some(oneElement => oneElement === value));

const mergedArray = [ 
  ...showid, 
  ...swipeeachotheruserId.filter(value => !duplicates.some(oneDuplicate => oneDuplicate === value))
];

const arrayWithoutDuplicate = mergedArray.filter(oneElem => !duplicates.some(value => oneElem === value));

console.log(duplicates);
console.log(mergedArray);
console.log(arrayWithoutDuplicate);
```